# How to use Prometheus to monitor grpc-java server and client?

Tags: prometheus, grpc-java

I want to use Prometheus to monitor my grpc server and grpc client ? but I don't know how to listen on the port of GRPC server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prometheus does not support grpc as a scrape protocol, so you either need to open a separate http port or use some kind of prometheus push gateway. https://github.com/coreos/prometheus-operator/issues/1969

If you are using spring-boot you can use https://github.com/yidongnan/grpc-spring-boot-starter which will automatically configure the metrics if spring-boot-actuator is present on your cp.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.devh</groupId>
    <artifactId>grpc-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
    <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Disclosure: I'm one of the core developers of grpc-spring-boot-starter.